# react.js doing autosubmit form when values = conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

so i have react login and register form buttons that call redux actions , but when values = conditions its calling automatickly and 2 actions dispatching in one time 
Its my code 
`

```
const LoginPage = p => {
    const [login, setLogin] = useState("")
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
    return(<div className="login-box">
 <form>
        <input className="input-login form-control" placeholder="Type your login here"onChange={(e) => setLogin(e.target.value)}/>
        <input className="input-login form-control" placeholder="Type your password here"   onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
   {login.length >= 4 && password.length >= 4 ? (<div ><button onClick={actionLogin(login,password)} className="btn  btn-primary login-btn">Login</button> 
        <button onClick={actionReg(login,password)} className="btn  btn-primary login-btn">Register</button>   </div>)
        : 
        (<div><button className="btn  btn-primary login-btn" disabled>Login</button> 
        <button className="btn  btn-primary login-btn" disabled>Register</button></div>)
        }
   </form>
    </div>)
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that when you generate the button this way:

`<button onClick={actionLogin(login,password)} ...`

you are executing the function. Try this way:

`<button onClick={() => actionLogin(login,password)} ...`

Same thing with actionReg function

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `actionLogin` and `actionReg` right away when the components are first rendered, rather than attaching click handlers to them.

These:

```
onClick={actionLogin(login,password)}
onClick={actionReg(login,password)}
```

should be:

```
onClick={() => actionLogin(login,password)}
onClick={() => actionReg(login,password)}
```

Also, rather than repeat the button components, you can just set the `disabled` state based on your condition:

```
const invalidPasswordOrLogin = login.length < 4 || password.length < 4

return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => actionLogin(login,password)} className="btn  btn-primary login-btn" disabled={invalidPasswordOrLogin}>Login</button> 
    <button onClick={() => actionReg(login,password)} className="btn  btn-primary login-btn" disabled={invalidPasswordOrLogin}>Register</button>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

When your condition matches, the buttons are rendered. But he onClick event handler attached to these are executed during the render process itself. And due to this, there are 2 dispatches. What you should instead do is to make the function to be called only after the button is clicked.

This can be achieved by modifying then `onClick` for buttons to something like below

```
<div>
    <button onClick={() => actionLogin(login,password)} className="btn  btn-primary login-btn">Login</button> 
    <button onClick={() => actionReg(login,password)} className="btn  btn-primary login-btn">Register</button>
</div>
```

You have done correctly on the `onChange` event for inputs. Then i hope you understand why this type of syntax is necessary for the buttons too or where ever you pass the functions.